# IndexOutOfBoundsExecption error

Tags: android, arraylist

In my program, I have an SQLite that stores GPS coordinates for google maps in my application.
I try to retrieve the latitude and longitude and store them in a arrayList, but the program throws indexOutOfBoundsException when I run the program. I vaguely understand that this means there's nothing in the arrayList when I try to retrieve a item from it, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

*LogCat*

```
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidbasic12/com.example.androidbasic12.map}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at com.example.androidbasic12.map.onCreate(map.java:58)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-22 14:39:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(21639):    ... 11 more
```

*The raw query in class "DatabaseHandler.class"*

```
    public Cursor getLatLng(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARCOORD + " WHERE name = " + CAR_KEY_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;

}
```

*Class "UserFunction.class"*

```
    public ArrayList<String> getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();
    ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
        cordarr.add(lat);
        cordarr.add(lng);
    }
cursor.close();
db.close();
return cordarr;
}
```

*map.class*

```
    UserFunctions userFunc = new UserFunctions();
    ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    cordarr = userFunc.getCoords(getApplicationContext(), Lat1, Lng1);
    Lat1 = cordarr.get(0);
    Lng1 = cordarr.get(1);
    lat = goDouble(Lat1);
    lng  = goDouble(Lng1);
    LatLng sala = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

*Function that takes strings and convert to double for use in googlemaps*

```
    public Double goDouble(String Latlng) {
    Double goDouble = Double.parseDouble(Latlng);
    return goDouble;
}
```

Comment: are you sure your cursor is not empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have null check here,

```
    public ArrayList<String> getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();
        if (cursor !null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
              ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
            lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
            lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
            cordarr.add(lat);
            cordarr.add(lng);
            return cordarr;
        }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return null;
    }
```

and here too,

```
    UserFunctions userFunc = new UserFunctions();
    ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    cordarr = userFunc.getCoords(getApplicationContext(), Lat1, Lng1);
    if(cordarr != null && cordarr.size() > 1) {
    Log.d("LOG","have got lat long to show.")
    Lat1 = cordarr.get(0);
    Lng1 = cordarr.get(1);
    lat = goDouble(Lat1);
    lng  = goDouble(Lng1);
    LatLng sala = new LatLng(lat, lng); 
    } else {
        Log.d("LOG","no lat long found")
    }
```

will u try this and let me see what logs u are getting

Comment: Thanks, this showed me the problem. I seem to have some errors in my PHP files that parse the data from the MySql database, and that causes my local SQLite database to have no values.

Comment: Good then, u know where is the error now. :) go ahead and solve it. let me know if you need nything  from my side, before u accept my Answer( mark it as accept))

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
           lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
           lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
           cordarr.add(lat);
           cordarr.add(lng);
     }
```

But You have to set securely the cursor to the first position, or Do You really want only get datas if the cursor is on first? If not, call

```
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

and then get Your data, but inside the if clause:

```
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
    lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
    cordarr.add(lat);
    cordarr.add(lng);

     cursor.moveToNext(); //call this, so the cursor goes to the next
}
```

Comment: Nice, And why one needs to call moveToFirst() method twice? wont it work in if condition it self ??

Comment: Tried this and it gave the same error. I also tried to set `cursor.moveToFirst`before the If, and then `if (cursor != null) {
    lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
    lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
    cordarr.add(lat);
    cordarr.add(lng);

    cursor.moveToNext();` and it gave the same error.

Comment: ok, so, are You sure that Your method getLatLng() returns a valid cursor? Is it possible that a) your table is not created and/or b) your CAR_KEY_NAME is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate the cursor.

```
if(cursor!=null)
 {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
    lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
    lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
    cordarr.add(lat);
    cordarr.add(lng);
   }while(cursor.moveToNext()); //It will move to next value.
  }
```

Comment: This solution will actually move to step ahead, we whould not use movetonext as last last statement of while, while condition will move to next item and return true or false, No?

Comment: :).. Good to hear u got that point,even though there were some spelling mistakes.  it was "move two(not to) " and "should (not whould)" it was a typo :)

Comment: @Ankit sorry what do you mean spelling mistake. Where you saying?

Comment: I was mentioning spelling mistakes in my 1st comment.